# keras classification problem, error in model.fit command

Tags: tensorflow, keras, classification

'I want to solve a classification problem by keras.model, but after running model.fit I face to a dimension error. I have run following code:'

```
print(X_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
```

'output:'

```
(2588, 39436)
(2588, 6)

model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.Input(shape=(39436,1)),
        layers.Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, strides=5, activation="relu"),
        layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=10),
        layers.Conv1D(64, kernel_size=3, strides=5, activation="relu"),
        layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=10),
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dropout(0.5),
        layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax"),
    ]
)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

'After running following code, '

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=15, validation_split=0.3)
```

'I give this error:'

ValueError: in user code:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_1 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 39436]

'It would be appreciated if you guide me what would be the issue?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input array, as per the error message, has a shape `[None, 39436]`. However, in your `Input` layer, you pass in a shape `[39436, 1]`, which matches to `[None, 39436, 1]` where `None` represents the samples dimension. This is the error that is being thrown.

You need to match the shapes, either by:

**1. Reshaping your input data** to have a shape of `[samples, 39436, 1]`, leaving the model architecture unchanged.

This can be done as (suppose train_X are your input features):

```
train_X = np.expand_dims(train_X, axis=2)
```

`np.expand_dims` adds a new dimension to the array at index 2 of the shape of the array. So here it reshapes `[samples, 39436]` to `[samples, 39436, 1]`.

Refer: [NumPy docs for expand_dims](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html)

**OR**

**2. Change the** `input_shape` **parameter** in the `Input` layer to accept a shape of `[39436,]`, so as to match your data.

Comment: Many thanks for your support. But the solution did not work. Really the input shape is as following, at first:   print(X_train.shape)
'output:'
(2588, 39436)

Comment: I was a little prepoccupied while I wrote the answer. I have changed it. This should work now as explained above.